# Binary search output

Tags: javascript

So I was working with some binary searches trying to find if a number is a square again, and I don't exactly know how to show an output if "found" does not equal true

I tried putting it in the while loop and it gave me an output but it kept looping "Your number is not a square" over and over again. But if I put it outside the loop I get no output at all

```js
     //perform Binary search 
  right = SIZE;
  left = 0;
  found = false;

  while (left <= right && (!found)) {
  index = Math.floor((left + right) / 2);

  if (numberArray[index] == searchNumber) {

    found = true;
    document.write("Your number is a square!");

    if (numberArray[index] != searchNumber) {
      found != true;
      document.write("Your number is not a square")
    }

  }

  //output
  index++;

  //print message not true
  if (numberArray[index] > searchNumber) {
    right = index - 1;

  } else {
    left = index + 1;
  }
}
```

The intended result is to have the program find out if a number is a square using a binary search and having an output if it doesn't

Comment: did you mean `found = false` in the line before `document.write("Your number is not a square")` ?

Comment: Why are you using a separate `if` statement? Just use `if (...) {...} else {...}`.

Comment: The indentation of this code is all over the place, making it hard to read.

Comment: sorry I tried your fix Andrew it didn't work and I don't know what you mean Jack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A problem here is the fact your second `if` statement will never run because its inside the first `if` that is the opposite comparison.

for example, for the same `index` and `searchNumber` it will never happen that both `if (numberArray[index] == searchNumber)` and `if (numberArray[index] != searchNumber) {` will be `true`

Move the second `if` out of the first one. Since your 2nd `if` was just the opposite of the first `if` you can just put it in a `else` clause (what Jack was talking about)

Also `found != true;` should be `found = false`

```js
//perform Binary search 
right = SIZE;
left = 0;
found = false;

while (left <= right && (!found)) {
  index = Math.floor((left + right) / 2);

  if (numberArray[index] == searchNumber) {
    found = true;
    document.write("Your number is a square!");
  } else {
    found = false;
    document.write("Your number is not a square")
  }


  //output
  index++;

  //print message not true
  if (numberArray[index] > searchNumber) {
    right = index - 1;

  } else {
    left = index + 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that fixed my problem!

Comment: glad to help out

Comment: @YeetersonPeeterson You can click the checkmark next to the answer to accept the answer.  Then both you and he get some rep.  See [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)